# "'ssh' is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I get such an error in the terminal `'ssh' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.` while installing Raspberry Pi 3 Model B + internet.I want to perform the operation on Windows in a headless way.) What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

```
For Windows, first install the git base from here: https://git-scm.com/downloads

Next, set the environment variable:
Press Windows+R and type sysdm.cpl
Select advance -> Environment variable
Select path-> edit the path and paste the below line:
C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe

To test it, open the command window: press Windows+R, type cmd and then type ssh.
```